# Remove all occurrences of strings at the beginning of line with regexp

Tags: python, regex

I have a set of some words that i want to remove from beginning of a string.
For example: `set = {"aba", "bcd"}`
For string `"aba bcd aba aba aaa"` result should be `"aaa"`, and for string
`"bcd abacaba"` result should be `"abacaba"`.

I tried this

```
import re
inp = "lalala bababa qqqq n"
pat = re.compile(r"^([la |ba ]+")

print pat.sub("+", inp)
```

but output is

```
+qqqq n
```

I don't understand, why it ignore all witespaces?
What is correct regexp?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regex for word `aba` followed by one or more spaces is `'aba +'`.
Regex for word `bcd` followed by one or more spaces is `'bcd +'`.
Regex for either of those is `'(aba +|bcd +)'`.
That repeated one or more times is `'(aba +|bcd +)+'`.

Replacing that with empty string:

```
re.sub(r'(aba +|bcd +)+', '', 'aba bcd aba aba aaa')
```

Enforcing that the searched string is at the beginning:

```
re.sub(r'^(aba +|bcd +)+', '', 'aba bcd aba aba aaa')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
inp = "lalala bababa qqqq n"
inp = inp.split()
```

inp is now `['lalala','bababa','qqqq','n']`

so take the last part with

```
inp[-1]
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what you probably wanted instead:

```
In [28]: pat = re.compile(r"^(la |ba )+")

In [29]: pat.sub('+', 'lalala bababa qqqq n')
Out[29]: 'lalala bababa qqqq n'

In [30]: pat.sub('+', 'la ba qqqq n')
Out[30]: '+qqqq n'
```